# Is SVN global ignore recursive?

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN, and I want to ignore a directory recursively, like in Git. I have a directory, `sample`, which I want to ignore recursively.

```
>svn status
sample/first/1.jpg
sample/second/2.jpg
sample/third/3.jpg
```

I have tried:

1. `svn ps svn:ignore "*" .` (under the `sample` directory)
2. Setting global ignores in `~/.subversion/config` as `global-ignores = sample`.

But still it shows the same result when I run `svn status`:

```
>svn status
sample/first/1.jpg
sample/second/2.jpg
sample/third/3.jpg
```

How can I recursively ignore a directory in SVN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ignore the directory `samples` and all the content within, you must set `svn:ignore` in the directory *containing* the `samples` directory. You did it within `samples` itself. Please note two things:

1. `svn:ignore` affects only unversions files. This means, that files and directories already known to SVN will still show up.
2. `svn:ignore` settings are not cumulative or recursive. If you want to ignore *only* the *.jpg files in you treee, you have to set `svn:ignore` to `*.jpg` in each directory.

Please note, that the command `svn propset` has an `-R` (aka. recursive) option, which *might* help. But keep in mind, that `propset` is not `propadd`. This is of course only a concern if you want to set different values in the tree.

Answer (score 7):

`svn -R propset svn:ignore . -F somefile.txt`

Where somefile.txt is a file containing all the svn ignore patterns you want recursively set.

Comment: I just ran ` svn -R propset svn:ignore -F .\ignorePatterns.txt` and received the following error: `svn: E205001: Explicit target argument required`

Comment: @ShaunLuttin In my example, the svn:ignore is done on the current working directory '.' (it doesn't have quotes around it in my example).  In your example, you omitted the directory and moved the dot to make a relative path of a file '.\ignorePatterns.txt'.  You can't commit a set of properties against _nothing_, as SVN is based on a virtual file system.  You need to commit the properties against a directory or file.

Comment: Will above command automatically takes care of newly added directories as well (after above command is run)?

Comment: @KrishPrabakar No, this would not set properties on directories that don't exist.  SVN is a revisioned file system; and, you can't set permissions / ownership / properties on non existing directories or files.  To attempt to do something like that, you'd have to reconfigure all SVN clients, which isn't really the right way to go about it.  Better to have a review system, and a policy checking such things upon review to merge.

Comment: Refer "svn:global-ignores" (by @markmnl) answer below for solution for SVN 1.8 +

Answer (score 4):

There is a new SVN property to do this from SVN 1.8 onwards. See the bottom of [this page from the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html):

```
svn:global-ignores
```

It applies to the folder you set it on and everything underneath, and you do not need to specify recursive. For example, to set on the current directory:

```
svn propset svn:global-ignores "bin obj" .
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.ignore :

"The patterns found in the svn:ignore property apply only to the directory on which that property is set, and not to any of its subdirectories."

[...]

"Once an object is under Subversion's control, the ignore pattern mechanisms no longer apply to it. In other words, don't expect Subversion to avoid committing changes you've made to a versioned file simply because that file's name matches an ignore pattern—Subversion always notices all of its versioned objects."

You could use the -R flag but that only applies the property recursivly - it doesn't change the properties effect so won't apply to any new directories created.

Also I suggest using propedit instead of ps as it allows mulitline edit, otherwise it's tricky to deal with more than one ignore pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For those on *nix:

Although the documentation implies that `~.subversion/config` should already have the default configuration in it, mine (SVN 1.6.17 on Ubuntu) was empty.

Here's the format I finally got to work (this is the entire file), includes the default settings and I've added *.ignore on the end:

```
[Miscellany]
global-ignores=*.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store *.ignore
```